# Eclipse Shows Missing Interface Methods on Child Class, Not Parent Class

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

In Eclipse, **why are missing interface methods shown on a child class, and not on the parent class?**

Let's say I have a simple interface:

```
public interface ISpeaks {
  String talk();
}
```

Then, I have this interface implemented on a class which is extended:

```
public abstract class Cat implements ISpeaks {
  // forgot to implement talk()
}

public class Tiger extends Cat {
  // also didn't implement talk()
}
```

Eclipse complains that **Tiger is missing the method talk()** (exact error: `The type Tiger must implement the inherited abstract method ISpeaks.talk()`). I expect it to tell me that **Cat** is missing talk(), because Cat is the class that explicitly implements the interface. Not Tiger.

This is definitely a "buh?" moment for me, because I'm in Spring/Hibernate and whenever I add a method to my DAO interfaces, I get an error like this for every database-aware test case that there's a method missing -- instead of getting a single error on the base test method that mocks my DAOs.

Comment: Are you sure you didnt mark your Cat class as abstract ?

Comment: I did indeed mark it as abstract. Still, it's an abstract method that implements an interface.

Comment: Also, there is no reason to use `public` in your method declaration in ISpeak.  Interface methods are automatically `public` and `abstract`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the `Cat` class is abstract, you do not have to implement all the interface methods.

You will only have to implement all the interface methods on concrete classes which implement `ISpeaks`, like `Tiger`.

This is logical, because there is no way to instantiate an object of type `Cat`, so there is no way to create an object which does not fully implement the interface.

A similar example is given in the last paragraph of http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: I removed abstract (which was unnecessary) and I get what I expect. Thanks.

Comment: @ashes999 - if you won't ever need to create unspecialized `Cat` instances then it is correct to declare it as `abstract`.

Comment: @Stephen C. You're right, but this gives me false negatives. I guess I'll just have to live with it.